# How to fill density plot within an interval with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, fill, density-plot

The code below fills each of the two densities with color under the area of the curve:

```
library(ggplot2)

#fake data
dat <- data.frame(dens = c(rnorm(100), rnorm(100, 2, 0.5))
                   , group = rep(c("C", "P"), each = 100))

#fill the area under the curve
ggplot(dat, aes(x = dens, fill = group)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.75)
```

How can I achieve the following two goals?

1) Only fill each curve within a specified interval. For example, interval [-1.5, 2.0] for group 'C' and [0.5, 2.8] for group 'P'.

2) Add a vertical segment (from x-axis to the curve) for each density. For example, at x=0.2 for group 'C' and at x=1.9 for group 'P'.

Comment: Lots of different answers at the linked questions. You can use some clever grouping, or (perhaps easier in this case) calculate the densities yourself beforehand. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: @Axeman Thanks! Those links do help. However, there are two densities involved in the same plot in my case. How to deal with that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get you stared, here's your first question:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

as.data.frame.density <- function(x) data.frame(x = x$x, y = x$y)

densities <- dat %>% 
  group_nest(group) %>% 
  mutate(dens = map(data, ~as.data.frame(density(.$dens)))) %>% 
  unnest(dens)

ggplot(densities, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group)) + 
  geom_density(stat = 'identity') +
  geom_density(
    aes(fill = group),
    . %>% filter((group == "C" & between(x, -1.5, 2.0)) | (group == "P" & between(x, 0.5, 2.8))),
    stat = 'identity',
    alpha = 0.75
  )
```

[image]

There are other ways of calculating the densities per group, using `dplyr` is just one way. It is probably good to set an equal bandwidth to the two density estimations.

Adding the segments is similar to this approach, you just need to find the correct values in the `densities` data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Is the `map()` function from the package `purrr`? Also, I got the following error: `Error in as.data.frame.default(density(.$dens)) : cannot coerce class ‘"density"’ to a data.frame`

Comment: Just one more small correction: `library(tidyr)`. Thanks a lot!